# How can I prove this equation using Einstein summation?

Tags: vectors

I need to prove this equation:
 $$(\vec A \times \vec B) \cdot[(\vec B \times \vec C)\times(\vec C \times \vec A)] = [\vec A \cdot (\vec B \times \vec C)]^2$$

But I need to use the Einstein summation. I tried doing it multiple times, with every detail I possibly could and I think I'm straying very far from the right answer because it's coming out very complicated and from what I understand is that it's supposed to be more simple than doing it with all of the linear algebra. This is what I tried:

$$(\vec A \times \vec B)_i \cdot[(\vec B \times \vec C)\times(\vec C \times \vec A)]_i$$
$$=\bigl(\epsilon _{ijk}A_jB_k\bigl)\Bigl[\epsilon_{ijk}(\vec B \times \vec C)_j(\vec C \times \vec A)_k\Big]$$
$$=\bigl(A_jB_k-A_kB_j\big)\Big[\big(\vec B \times \vec C\big)_j\big(\vec C \times \vec A\big)_k-\big(\vec B \times \vec C\big)_k\big(\vec C \times \vec A\big)_j\Big]$$
$$\big(\vec B \times \vec C\big)_j=\epsilon_{jki}B_kC_i=\big(B_kC_i-B_iC_k\big)$$
for every term inside the brackets I followed the same process as I did in the last step. It quickly became very messy and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've been trying to follow what I've found online, I've found [this website](http://www-astro.physics.ox.ac.uk/~sr/lectures/vectors/lecture10final.pdfc) to be the most helpful.

I tried to work backwards from the RHS:
$$\big[\vec A \cdot \big(\vec B \times \vec C\big)\big]^2$$
$$=\big[A_i\big(\vec B \times \vec C \big)_i\big]^2$$
$$=\big[A_i\big(\epsilon_{ijk}B_jC_k\big)\big]^2$$
$$=\big[A_i\big(B_jC_k-B_kC_j\big)\big]^2$$
$$=A_i^2B_j^2C_k^2-2A_i^2B_jB_kC_kC_j+A_i^2B_k^2C_j^2$$

This doesn't look right and was of no help to me. I also think it's not the final answer, either. I just didn't know what to do from there.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `I need to use the Einstein summation` Guess that means you are not allowed to just use the triple product identities?

Comment: @dxiv No, the problem has two parts to it. The first part identities are used, and the second part requires this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is required to prove that $$(\vec A \times \vec B) \cdot[(\vec B \times \vec C)\times(\vec C \times \vec A)] = [\vec A \cdot (\vec B \times \vec C)]^2$$

Writing the left hand side in Einstein summation notation: 
$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}&\epsilon_{ijk} A_j B_k \epsilon_{imn}[\epsilon_{mpq }B_p C_q \epsilon_{nrs}C_rA_s]\\
&=\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{imn}\epsilon_{mpq }\epsilon_{nrs}C_rA_s A_j B_k B_p C_q \\
&=(\delta_{jm}\delta_{kn}-\delta_{jn}\delta_{km})\epsilon_{mpq }\epsilon_{nrs}C_rA_s A_j B_k B_p C_q\\
&=\epsilon_{jpq }\epsilon_{krs}C_rA_s A_j B_k B_p C_q-\epsilon_{kpq }\epsilon_{jrs}C_rA_s A_j B_k B_p C_q\\
&=\epsilon_{krs}C_rA_s A_j B_k [B\times C]_j-\epsilon_{jrs}C_rA_s A_j B_k [B\times C]_k\\
&=\epsilon_{skr}B_k C_rA_s A_j [B\times C]_j-\epsilon_{jrs}C_rA_s A_j \cancel{(B\cdot (B\times C))}_{\text{equals 0}}\\
&=(A_s[B\times C]_s)(A_j[B\times C]_j)\\
&=(A\cdot[B\times C])^2\end{align}$$

Comment: Why, on the 5th line, did you put $B_p$ and $C_q$ into a cross product with the subscript j?

Comment: Oh I see now, $\epsilon_{jpq}B_pC_q = [B \times C]_j$

Comment: Yes, exactly :) In the 7th line, something similar happens with $[B\times C]_s$